# How to know if the SQL query is efficent according to the setup of the tables in the db?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlperformance

Is there any way I can check if my sql query is performing at its best? Im using sql server 2008. E.g. I would like to know if my query hits the expected index.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, include the "actual execution plan". It is located in the Query menu in SQL Management Studio.
The execution plan will show you which kind of joins and indexes the query uses.

Answer (score 2):

Use execution plans to profile your query. See this tutorial for more information: 
http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/

Answer (score 2):

Whilst the chaps have already suggested analysing the execution plan (and rightly so!) there is another method that is a tad more friendly to people not familiar with execution plans, in MSSMS, highlight your query and right-click the selection and hit "Analyse Query in Database Tuning Advisor" - be patient and wait for the advisor to open and the database selection tab to open, once open, select the databases your query interacts with and click "Start Analysis".

This will do a rough check of all the tables, joins and so on, it will analyse the execution plan and tell you what indexes "might" help in making the query faster (i.e. avoiding table scans).

Don’t blindly accept what it suggests though, take a backup of your database first, run the analyser - apply the recommendations, benchmark if your query performs better – rinse & repeat.

For example, if your query is reading large tables, you might find that the tuning advisor suggests the creation of an index that would cost you a lot of diskspace but only gain a minor speed improvement – this is where you would have to ask the question “is it worth it?” – This is why experimenting with the analysers suggestions is usually a good idea!

Between tests, make sure you clear your cache to make sure you get accurate results:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE; 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
```

Also, for more accurate benchmarking, use `SET STATISTICS TIME ON;` - dont rely on the counter inside MSSMS - it can lag sometimes.